Need Help Proving That These Functions are Natural Transformations
In MacLane's Sheaves in Geometry and Logic, it is stated the following.

Now, consider a given presheaf $P$ and the sheaf $\Gamma \Lambda_P$ of sections of the bundle $\Lambda_P \rightarrow X$. For each open subset $U$ of $X$ there is a function:
$$ \eta_U:P(U) \rightarrow \Gamma \Lambda_P(U), \eta_U(s)= \dot{s} $$ The process of restricting $s$ to an open subset of $U$ clearly matches the $\eta$'s, so $\eta$ is a natural transformation.

However, I am not really understanding how he concludes that $\eta$ is a natural transformation.
Here $s \in P(U)$  and $\dot{s}: U \rightarrow \Lambda_P$ where $\dot{s}(x)= \text{germ}_x s$ where $x \in U$.
Thanks!

What have you tried?

@BrunoB I tried building the naturality square with $\eta_U:P(U) \rightarrow \Gamma \Lambda_P(U)$ and $\eta_U:P(V) \rightarrow \Gamma \Lambda_P(V)$ as the rows and and $P(U) \rightarrow P(V)$ (because $i:V \rightarrow  U$) and tried verifying that it commutes. But i am having some trouble with understanding the composition $ \Gamma \Lambda_P(i) \circ \eta_U$.

@BrunoB But i didn't really understand MacLane's justification?

Consider two open subsets $V \subseteq U$ of $X$. We have to check that $\eta_U(s)|_V = \eta_V(s|_V)$, that is $\dot{s}|_V = \dot{(s|_V)}$, that is, for each $x \in V$, $\mathrm{germ}_x s = \mathrm{germ}_x (s|_V)$. This is completely obvious by the definition of a germ.
